# Custom Sharepoint 2013 page layout throws error

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I'm trying to create a custom page layout for Sharepoint 2013. So far the only changes I've made to the Design Manager template are linking a CSS file (linked within the PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead section), and added divs, each containing a Web Part zone, to the PlaceHolderMain section. The page layout previews with no problem, but when I try to set it as the layout for an actual Sharepoint page, I get this error:

The DataSourceID of 'TopNavigationMenu' must be the ID of a control of type IHierarchicalDataSource.  A control with ID 'topSiteMap' could not be found.

I've tried googling this error, but all the instances of it I can find are caused by custom web parts etc. Does anyone know what could be causing it here?

EDIT: I have confirmed I am site collection administrator, and I checked the logs. They don't mention anything new, but here's the full error from the logs just to be clear:

11/19/2014 14:44:02.10  w3wp.exe (0x20C0)                           0x2598  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium      Application error when access /aa/Pages/default.aspx, Error=The DataSourceID of 'TopNavigationMenu' must be the ID of a control of type IHierarchicalDataSource.  A control with ID 'topSiteMap' could not be found.   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.GetDataSource()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.ConnectToHierarchicalDataSource()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.... 1fbccd9c-39f9-c07e-674b-2ee9a47b3002

11/19/2014 14:44:02.10* w3wp.exe (0x20C0)                           0x2598  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium      ...UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  1fbccd9c-39f9-c07e-674b-2ee9a47b3002

11/19/2014 14:44:02.10  w3wp.exe (0x20C0)                           0x2598  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Web.HttpException: The DataSourceID of 'TopNavigationMenu' must be the ID of a control of type IHierarchicalDataSource.  A control with ID 'topSiteMap' could not be found.    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.GetDataSource()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.ConnectToHierarchicalDataSource()     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolea... 1fbccd9c-39f9-c07e-674b-2ee9a47b3002

11/19/2014 14:44:02.10* w3wp.exe (0x20C0)                           0x2598  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...n includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   1fbccd9c-39f9-c07e-674b-2ee9a47b3002

Comment: Edited to show progress (commented because I can't delete comments.)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out the problem was in my master page. I was using Seattle, so I switched to Oslo and the problem went away.